# WSUS Manual Update

Tags: wsus

I have a WSUS server and I want to manually place patches on it. It is the intention that this WSUS serve will then update other servers with the aforementioned patches. Is this a viable option with WSUS ?

Comment: Isn't that a built in function? You set your WSUS to not automaticly accept updates then you can approve which updates you want.

Comment: -1 for obviously not even reading the product description on the [WSUS Home Page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/bb332157). It's not just a built in function; it's one of the two primary purposes of WSUS (the other being to cache the updates).

Comment: Captain Obvious is...

Comment: Chris et al, you misunderstand my question. My WSUS server has no connectivity to the internet at all. The update must be retreieve from another source (can be another WSUS server) and MANUALLY installed. Is this viable??

Comment: @thugzclub, read the documentation. Everything you are asking about IS covered. There are quite clear details about what you need to do to achieve your goals. It may not be quite the way you hope to do it but that's another issue altogether. RTFM.

Comment: @thugzclub good info to include in the original question. "My WSUS server has no access to the internet." I'm still not understanding what you mean by Manually install updates. On where? Do you mean import the updates manually into the WSUS server, or manually install the updates on the workstations? Or is what @Ryan M. posted what you're looking for?

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you're looking for? http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/home.aspx. Allows you to manually download updates from Microsoft and import them into your WSUS server.

Comment: I've looked at this website.  It is entirely inadequate for keeping WSUS up to date; search doesn't work properly, and many Windows 10 Updates that I have are not even listed on the site.  It appears that the only reasonable advice on the Internet is to have two WSUS servers, one of which is actually connected to the Internet so that it can download updates.  You can then export the updates and import them to your isolated WSUS.